# Why does React onChange work even without losing focus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A function like this in HTML will only work when you move focus out of the input field:

```
<input onchange="changeInput()" type="text"></input>
```

But in React, `onChange` with a controlled input will trigger even without losing focus:

```
<input value={this.state.textVal} onChange={this.changeInput} type="text"></input>
```

Is this because of Synthetic Events or something else? I could not find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The actual browser event that fires the callback is passed as the `nativeEvent` property of a React event. By passing `console.log` as a callback to the `onChange` of an `input` element, we can see that the native event is of type `'input'`.

This behavior can be replicated using the JavaScript `addEventListener` method:

```js
const setValue = ({ target }) => {
  document.getElementById("myresult").innerHTML = target.value;
}

document.getElementById("myinput").addEventListener("input", setValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<p id="myresult"></p>
```